# How to show the summation in each row of a measure with some conditions?

Tags: python, sql, r

Let's suppose that I have the following data:

```
CustomerID->Number->Date

1->2->1/1/2019,
1->3->2/1/2019,
2->1->1/1/2019,
2->6->2/1/2019
```

I want to have a column let's call it `Summation`:

```
CustomerID->Number->Date->Summation

1->2->1/1/2019->2,
1->3->2/1/2019->5,
2->1->1/1/2019->1,
2->6->2/1/2019->7
```

I want that column `Summation` in each row to represent the total summation of customer from the first of the month until the day each row has.

How to do this in Python, SQL, or R?

Comment: You could use SQL. Use a window function partitioned by `CustomerID` on top of a `SUM()`. Here it is: `select
  CustomerID, Number, Date,
  sum(Number) over(partition by CustomerID order by Date) as Summation
from my_table`

Comment: @trotta Using your higher privileges, you have deleted quite a large part of the prose of the post (admittedly useless noise). That kind of fill-in is usually posted by newbies, which thereby circumvent the systems mechanism to prevent posts with insufficiet prose explanation. With your reputation, you should understand that this is not promoting StackOverflows purposes.

Comment: Hi Arturo, welcome to SO! Handy hint: it might help your case to post a code snippet/sample of the code (or query) you used when you tried to solve this problem. It might also help to ask for the answer in a single programming language (whichever one you need/want the most), since the answer will vary a lot based on the target language. Finally, I don't think the `machine-learning` tag is appropriate for this question (it's more about database manipulation/modelling) so I've edited your question to remove it, pending review. Don't be put off - there's lot's to learn in how to use SO ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server

```
SELECT CustomerID,Number, DATE, SUM(Number) over (partition by CustomerID order by Date) as summation
from tab_name
```